# Feeding higher voltage sine wave to Arduino interrupt pin

Tags: arduino, voltage, pulse, detection, edge

I want to use Arduino to count cycles from a bicycle generator. This generator has variable frequency (which I want to measure), but also variable voltage that is proportional to wheel speed, typically being above 6V.

What I want is a way to limit the voltage of the wave so that I can detect the rising of a pin voltage (`attachInterrupt(pin, RISING)` or maybe `pulseIn(pin, HIGH)`).

My doubt concerns either voltage limiting (for which I'd think about a 5V zener), but also impedance, since I don't want to drain current from the generator (which has to power the rest of the bike circuitry).

Is the zener idea correct? What other components should I add, and how should they be combined?

I know there is something called a Schmidt trigger, but I don't know exactely how I could use it here (and frankly, I'd rather not to use an IC if not needed).

Comment: I'd half-wave rectify the dynamo's output and then use a precision low-current shunt reference to clamp the voltage to something the Arduino can stand, (see my preliminary answer below) but how do you plan on running the Arduino? And what's the maximum peak-to-peak voltage the dynamo will output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Zener idea is correct, and since you're concerned about loading the dynamo, you could use something like this, where the LM4040 draws less than 1 mA:

[image]

As I understand it, the Arduino's MCU sports internal pullups, so the LM4040 will clamp the dynamo's negative half-cycle to about 500 mV below ground, and R2R3 will limit the negative voltage into the interrupt pin to about 250 millivolts, which will keep the input protection diodes happy.

Comment: I plan to run the arduino with rechargeable battery pack through DC in plug (so I get the internal regulation and protection benefit). The dynamo generates around 6V RMS nominal, subject to frequency and amplitude fluctuations. Also, the dynamo output is not sinusoidal (as I have already checked with an oscilloscope), but has some short spikes of 40+ volts, which I currently shut up using a rectifier bridge, a 6V Zener, and a 6800uF capacitor (but these are for the rest of the bike circuitry, not for the Arduino).

Comment: I did almost exactely the same thing yesterday. Only that I already have the generator rectified at this point, so I didn't feel the need to use R2. Also I am using a plain Zener diode instead of the LM4040. It's working fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There's a dirty method of connecting AC to a microcontroller - just use a resistor.

I happen to have the Atmega datasheet open, it shows you that the input pin looks like this:
[image: Arduino input pin model]
The two diodes on the left are for ESD protection, they shunt any overvoltage to earth or to the 5V rail.  You can abuse these diodes to clip your AC signal to the range 0-5 V.

Selecting a resistor: use the largest possible value that will reliably drive the pin. Leakage current is 1 uA, and the capacitance is 10 pF. If your dynamo frequency tops out at 1 kHz, the input impedance will be around 1.5 MOhm. 1 uA leakage will also become a problem in the MOhm range. If you choose a resistor near 100 kOhm, and the voltage rises to +10V, the current into the protection diodes will have a peak of perhaps 20 uA, which won't cause any harm.

Things to consider:

- This only works if the AC voltage is higher than 5 V. If it is lower, try using the comparator module to compare it to a 1 V reference you make with a resistive divider.
- If the arduino is powered by the AC voltage, then think carefully about where you connect the AC, and ground. I am currently doing it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh4cTn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- You might need to do something different depending on the ground reference of the AC source.

All of the above is really dirty and unprofessional. Good for a quick frequency counter or zero-crossing detector for a circuit. If you're going to sell the product or show it to anyone else, you should definitely use a diode clamp and a Schmitt trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am quite beginner with electronics: when yo umention "diode clamp", what exactely do you mean? Which kind of diode is this, and how is it supposed to be used? Wikipedia suggests that "diode _clipper_" could be somewhat more like I was thinking, would it?

Comment: I mean either a low enough voltage zener,  which I see above you're already using, or a pair of diodes that do the same job as the internal ones. The advantage of using your own external diode(s) is that you can then divide the voltage down a bit with resistors, so it swings from 0.5 to 4.5 V, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with the [schmitt trigger](http://www.solarbotics.net/bftgu/tutorials_schmitt.html) idea because it does provide nice clean transitions to your digital input which is really what you want for your interrupt input. Also you do not need to use an IC to build a schmitt trigger, you can build an schmitt trigger from BJTs like the one in the picture.

Also wikipedia had a good explanation on [schmitt triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)
 [image]

Comment: Do you think I could use an IC (for example, the 4093) with some form of pull-down or pull-up resistors and the Zener?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you have series resistor the zener diode to clamp the signal to less than Vdd. The circuit I showed in the picture its nice because you can build it with the 3906 and 3904 BJT and just resistors without the need for extra IC and zeners.